# Interpreting curves in Unity 3d

Tags: unity

I know that the I can allow the user to draw curves in game by line tracer.

if I want to interpret it, I could use handwritten text recognizer.

But what if I had to interpret a curve, where the user draws a symbol that has no literal meaning, only an in-game meaning, and interpret the meaning of the symbol as I define it?

Can I define my own way of interpreting the symbols?

Comment: Please do not post duplicate questions. If you edit your original question to be on-topic and focused to an answerable scope, it can be re-opened for answers.

Comment: @DMGregory  Ok so can you reopen my edited question please?

Comment: Your closed question is still too broad, as I've explained in the comments. We expect you to research the links you've been given on writing/gesture recognition strategies, so you can start to implement your own solution. If you get stuck at a particular step along the way, you should edit your question to describe the one specific problem you need help solving to proceed with your solution. Be sure to include enough detail to fully describe the types of shapes you need to recognize so we have clear test cases to guide potential solutions.